# ANTLR 4 : Bad grammar and 'no viable alternative at input'

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, token, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR 4 like that:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream;

public class Builder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CharStream input = new ANTLRInputStream("ON M1==2 && M3 == 5 && (M2 > 1 || M5 <= 5.0) "
                                              + "DO P5:42 P4:10");
        ExprLexer lexer = new ExprLexer(input);
        TokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ExprParser parser = new ExprParser(tokens);
        ExprParser.ExpressionContext uu = parser.expression();
        for (int i = 0; i < uu.getChildCount(); ++i)
            System.out.println(uu.getChild(i));
    }
}
```

And the following grammar:

```
grammar Expr;
options
{
  // antlr will generate java lexer and parser
  language = Java;

}
WS      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
OP      : '&&' | '||';
COMP    : '==' | '<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=' | '!=';
INT     : [0-9]+;
REAL    : INT '.' INT | INT;

ACTION  : 'P' INT ':' INT;
MEASURE : 'M' INT;

// ***************** parser rules:
cond       : MEASURE COMP REAL;
condexpr   : '(' condexpr ')' | cond OP condexpr | cond;
actionexpr : ACTION actionexpr | ACTION;
expression : 'ON' condexpr 'DO' actionexpr;
```

I have the following output:

```
line 1:7 no viable alternative at input 'M1==2'
ON
[29]
DO
[31]
```

I think I have an error in my grammar, but I do not see it.
Have you got an idea?

For your help,
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `INT` rule should be a `fragment` rule. As is, the expression `M1==2` is getting tokenized as [MEASURE, COMP, INT] instead of [MEASURE, COMP, REAL] like you expect.

```
fragment INT : [0-9]+;
```

Comment: Brilliant. A nice example of a requirement for the `fragment` keyword. This would be a great addition for AntrWorks to point out when it highlights errors in the graphical output.

Comment: Hello Mr.Sam, sorry to bother you, but can you please have a look at my problem here regarding write a rule name in unicode (rule name not rule body) and thanks =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614712/write-a-grammar-rule-name-in-unicode-antlr-4