# write a grammar rule name in unicode [ANTLR 4]

Tags: java, parsing, unicode, antlr, antlr4

I am still a beginner in ANTLR 4 and I was wondering if there is a way to write a grammar rule name in unicode. For example, the following rule is fine:

`atomExp returns [double value]
    :    n=Number                {$value = Double.parseDouble($n.text);}
    |    '(' exp=additionExp ')' {$value = $exp.value;}
    ;`

However, let's say I want to write the same rule but instead of writing its name as "atomExp" , I want to write the name as an Arabic word "تعبير"

`تعبير returns [double value]
    :    n=Number                {$value = Double.parseDouble($n.text);}
    |    '(' exp=additionExp ')' {$value = $exp.value;}
    ;`

but when I try to write it that way I get "no viable alternative" error. Can someone solve my problem please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `-encoding UTF-8` or such? That is, are string literals recognized correctly. I assume yes.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes I use the UTF-8 encoding, there is no problem recognizing literals in unicode, however, there is a problem in writing the rule name in unicode

Comment: That is sad; I never used Unicode names. You might try an accented latin char, or Chinese; to look whether it is whitespace (RTL/LTR) or indeed the Unicode letters. A one-letter character without diacritics might be tried. Just trying how far one comes.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks for your concern =) I followed your advice and tried with a Chinese character and it did not work too . . I believe it is confirmed that the problem is with the unicode names of rules. Do you know any way that I can work around this (tricks or so) so I can replace the rule name with another name? and again thanks for your concern :)

Comment: Just saw Bart's answer; adding Arabic script range(s), and adding LTR and RTL chars to whitespace would do. `'\u0600'..'\u06FF'
'\u0750'..'\u077F'
'\u08A0'..'\u08FF'
'\u0600'..'\u06FF'

LTR
'\u200E'
RTL
'\u200F'
`

Comment: @KhaledHassan, feel free to create an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues) with a request to broaden the set of characters for ANTLR's lexer- and parser-rule names.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks again, but can u provide me an explanation of adding LTR and RTL to whitespace ??

Comment: @BartKiers Okay I will be sure to do that =)

Comment: You can mention that to the ANTLR team in the issue/change request: Arabic script letter ranges, and both control chars Left-To-Right and Right-To-Left added to the whitespace token definition.

Comment: @JoopEggen okay, sure to mention that =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at [the lexer grammar for ANTLR4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr4/ANTLRv4Lexer.g4#L167), you can see that lexer and parser names support certain Unicode chars:

```
/** Allow unicode rule/token names */
ID  :   NameStartChar NameChar*;

fragment
NameChar
    :   NameStartChar
    |   '0'..'9'
    |   '_'
    |   '\u00B7'
    |   '\u0300'..'\u036F'
    |   '\u203F'..'\u2040'
    ;

fragment
NameStartChar
    :   'A'..'Z'
    |   'a'..'z'
    |   '\u00C0'..'\u00D6'
    |   '\u00D8'..'\u00F6'
    |   '\u00F8'..'\u02FF'
    |   '\u0370'..'\u037D'
    |   '\u037F'..'\u1FFF'
    |   '\u200C'..'\u200D'
    |   '\u2070'..'\u218F'
    |   '\u2C00'..'\u2FEF'
    |   '\u3001'..'\uD7FF'
    |   '\uF900'..'\uFDCF'
    |   '\uFDF0'..'\uFFFD'
    ; // ignores | ['\u10000-'\uEFFFF] ;

INT : [0-9]+
       ;
```

But it appears that your ID `تعبير` does not comply with the `NameChar*` part of the `ID` rule.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Bart for your reply =) But I meant to use the word تعبير as a rule name (instead of INT or ID) so when the parser tries to match a rule and it finds that the rule contains another rule written in Arabic for example, it calls it but the problem is I can't write a rule name in Arabic :( please correct me if I am wrong or misunderstood you and thanks again

Comment: and please excuse me for being naive (still my first time with ANTLR :D)
thanks again

Comment: @KhaledHassan that grammar on ANTLR4 itself specifies the above for names but is missing some scripts.

Comment: That is how ANTLR4 parses other (user defined) grammars. Every lexer- or parser-rule name must adhere to the rule I posted in my answer.

Comment: Umm, I don't know if it would make a difference, but when I tried to write the rule name تعبير but starting with an english letter it is accepted now . . so the whole problem is that I can't write a rule starting with an Arabic letter

Comment: @KhaledHassan, yeah, I would open an issue on the ANTLR issue tracker for this. Seems like a bug to me.